# pass parameter through URL and obtain on next page

Tags: asp.net, url

So each time a button is clicked a new page loads.  But the URl passed the BOQId with this URL

```
protected string GetURLForEditingBoqPricelist()
{
    return ResolveUrl(@"~/Boq.aspx?BOQ_Id=" + this.boqId.ToString());
}
```

loads the BOQ page and stores the BoqID so..

```
http://localhost:28889/Project/Boq.aspx?BOQ_Id=124
```

Then in the BOQ.aspx page how can i get the BOQid Value
just create a new int in the cs and make it equal to ??
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use, `int BOQid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["BOQ_Id"]);`

Answer (score 2):

```
int id;
Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["BOQ_Id"], out id);
```